# How do you ignore specific folders but keep certain contents in its subfolders?

Tags: github, lua, roblox

Just as a side note I am still relatively new to Github and Stack Overflow, so bear with me if I make any mistakes.

So as the title suggests, I am trying to ignore specific folders and only keep certain contents of its subfolders with `.gitignore`.

So in my case, I am trying to ignore the ReplicatedStorage and ProjectileCast folder while keeping the contents of the ProjectileCast folder. Essentially, I want the contents of the ProjectileCast folder to end up in the src folder.

[image: Here is what my folder structure looks like]

Here is what I have tried in my `.gitignore` file:

```
/*
!/src
/src/*
!/src/ReplicatedStorage
/src/ReplicatedStorage/*
!/src/ReplicatedStorage/ProjectileCast
```

The code above hasn't worked, so I am a little stuck. Please let me know what I can do to fix this. Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: If you want `ProjectileCast` inside of `src` why not just move it there? Why do you need to ignore `ReplicatedStorage`?\

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I want to keep the folder structure because I use an external program to code on Roblox, and keeping that specific structure is important. I could technically, move the code to src commit it to the repo, and then move it back but this sounds like a very inefficient way of doing things.

Comment: You probably just want to leave the structure as is. It'll make your project more readable and maintainable if you stick to a predefined standard structure, and just ignore anything that needs to be ignored. If you need this for a build process, it might make more sense to write a `Makefile`  or something to create the desired file tree in a temporary `build` directory before compiling

Answer (score 0):

With [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) you can define path patterns to ignore untracked files. What you are trying to do is a path rewrite, which is not possible in `.gitignore`.

If you really want to change the directory structure you would have to move the files. In this case you could automate it using [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) i.e. `pre-commit` and `post-checkout`. Note that you have to register client-side hooks when setting up your local repository so this is something to best document in the readme of your project.